# Reading Hive view created with CTE (With clause) from spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a view on Hive created with CTE (WITH clause) that, union two tables, then compute to show only the most recent record per id.
In my env, I have a tool for browsing hive databases (DBeaver, mandatory for non datalake dev to browse the data).

**View code**

```sql
    CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS db.test_cte_view AS
      with cte as (select * from db.test_cte union select * from db.test_cte_2),
       tmp as (SELECT id, idate, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY idate desc ) AS row_num from cte)
      SELECT cte.* from cte
         join (SELECT * from tmp where tmp.row_num =1) tmp_2
         on cte.id = tmp_2.id
         and cte.idate = tmp_2.idate
```

The issue is:

### when the view is created via beeline

(Which is our main way of creating tables and views in Hive)
I can easily browse on DBeaver, but, when running spark process to read from it it fails with the following:

```py
    ##pyspark
    spark.sql("select * from db.test_cte_view").show()

    'Table or view not found: cte; line 3 pos 56'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "DATA/fs3/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ingouagn/appcache/application_1552132357519_15102/container_e378_1552132357519_15102_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 545, in sql
      return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    File "/DATA/fs3/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ingouagn/appcache/application_1552132357519_15102/container_e378_1552132357519_15102_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
      answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    File "/DATA/fs3/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ingouagn/appcache/application_1552132357519_15102/container_e378_1552132357519_15102_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
      raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
    pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Table or view not found: cte; line 3 pos 56'
```

### When the view is created with sparl.sql("CREATE VIEW AS ...")

I can read it well with

```py
    ##pyspark
    spark.sql("select * from db.test_cte_view").show()
```

But, when trying to browse with DBeaver, it fails with something like:

```
Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 1:330 Failed to recognize predicate 'UNION'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in subquery source in definition of VIEW test_cte_view [
SELECT `gen_attr_0` AS `id`, `gen_attr_1` AS `status`, `gen_attr_2` AS `idate` FROM (SELECT `gen_attr_0`, `gen_attr_1`, `gen_attr_2` FROM ((SELECT `gen_attr_0`, `gen_attr_1`, `gen_attr_2` FROM (SELECT `id` AS `gen_attr_0`, `status` AS `gen_attr_1`, `idate` AS `gen_attr_2` FROM `db`.`test_cte`) AS gen_subquery_0) UNION DISTINCT (SELECT `gen_attr_5`, `gen_attr_6`, `gen_attr_7` FROM (SELECT `id` AS `gen_attr_5`, `status` AS `gen_attr_6`, `idate` AS `gen_attr_7` FROM `db`.`test_cte_2`) AS gen_subquery_1)) AS cte INNER JOIN (SELECT `gen_attr_3`, `gen_attr_4`, `gen_attr_8` FROM (SELECT `gen_attr_3`, `gen_attr_4`, `gen_attr_8` FROM (SELECT gen_subquery_4.`gen_attr_3`, gen_subquery_4.`gen_attr_4`, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY `gen_attr_3` ORDER BY `gen_attr_4` DESC NULLS LAST ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS `gen_attr_8` FROM (SELECT `gen_attr_3`, `gen_attr_4` FROM ((SELECT `gen_attr_3`, `gen_attr_9`, `gen_attr_4` FROM (SELECT `id` AS `gen_attr_3`, `status` AS `gen_attr_9`, `idate` AS `gen_attr_4` FROM `db`.`test_cte`) AS gen_subquery_2) UNION DISTINCT (SELECT `gen_attr_5`, `gen_attr_6`, `gen_attr_7` FROM (SELECT `id` AS `gen_attr_5`, `status` AS `gen_attr_6`, `idate` AS `gen_attr_7` FROM `db`.`test_cte_2`) AS gen_subquery_3)) AS cte) AS gen_subquery_4) AS gen_subquery_5) AS tmp WHERE (`gen_attr_8` = 1)) AS tmp_2 ON ((`gen_attr_0` = `gen_attr_3`) AND (`gen_attr_2` = `gen_attr_4`))) AS cte
] used as test_cte_view at Line 1:14
```

It seems the generated code is different between one way of creating the view to another.

Is there a way to make the first scenario (creating the view via beeline and accessing it via spark sql) work?

Thank you.

**spark: 2.1.1**  , **Hive: 1.2.1**

### Tables

```sql
     CREATE TABLE db.test_cte(
      id int, 
      status string, 
      idate date )
  
     CREATE TABLE db.test_cte_2(
      id int, 
      status string, 
      idate date )
```

populated with:

```sql
      insert into db.test_cte values
      (1,"green","2019-03-08"),
      (2,"green","2019-03-08"),
      (3,"green","2019-03-08"),
      (1,"red","2019-03-09"),
      (1,"yellow","2019-03-10"),
      (2,"gray","2019-03-09")
  
      insert into db.test_cte_2 values
      (10,"green","2019-03-08"),
      (20,"green","2019-03-08"),
      (30,"green","2019-03-08"),
      (10,"red","2019-03-09"),
      (10,"yellow","2019-03-10"),
      (20,"gray","2019-03-09")
```

**Edit**:
For anyone interested, I created an issue on Spark JIRA:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27203

Comment: 1st issue you mentioned 'Table or view not found: cte; line 3 pos 56' should be
spark.sql("select * from db.test_cte_view").show()
2.FAILED: SemanticException line 1:330 Failed to recognize predicate 'UNION'
This seems purely a Dbever issue(query works in spark-sql) check whether you can use union all instead of union

Comment: @rbyndoor sorry I do not understand your first point.  
For the second point, I can not modify the SQL code generated by spark when performing the create view statement, but changing union to union all into the view code doesn't fix the issue

Comment: I tried your above example. 1st issue i do not see any create view for dev_app_gvr_grover.test_cte_view
2nd one worked directly in spark-sql shell, So it must be problem alone in DbEver

Comment: ahh yeah my bad... for the first issue indeed I'll edit the post (but the issue still remains). For the  second, yes it works well in spark-shell and with spark session. I was wondering if there is a config or some other way to customize or config the spark SQL code generator, so that it would generate a code that can be interpreted by beeline

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with Spark2.1.1.2.6.1.0-129.  Upgrading to Spark2.4 solved the problem.

If upgrading is not an option, this workaround did the trick for me on 2.1:

```py
spark.table("db.my_view_with_ctes").registerTempTable("tmp")
spark.sql("select * from tmp")
```

This runs significantly longer than reading the view via spark-sql in Spark2.4 (over 10x the runtime for my use case), but it works.